Blazor Server - view-source - Body / Html not there?
I've got a blazor web site (view-source:https://teamkey.dk/) but if I try see it's view-source then everything that would be in the RenderBody() isn't shown. That's a bit of a problem for websites that want Google to read its content.
Anybody got any idea how to fix this?
I am expecting that when I go to view-source I get to see everything that would be in RenderBody. All the html content with class and styles tags like normal.

Try Pre-Rendering

I've already tried setting it like this:

And it doesn't help.

If pre-rendering isn't resolving the issue, you might need to check couple of additional stuff.
First of all, make sure your _Host.cshtml file is correctly set up.
On top of that, double check your main layout and component (App.razor) are properly configured to support pre-rendering. For example, the App.razor file should not have any issues that prevent it from rendering correctly.
In addition, check the browser's developer console for any JavaScript errors that might indicate problems with how Blazor is rendering content.
